# Java Pseudo-Hyperlink

Tags: java, swing

So I am working on something in Java right now where I need to display lots of JTextComponents. I need to be able to turn words in any text component into a hyperlink of sorts, specifically, when these words are clicked, some method is called. Please note, I am not looking for a REAL hyperlink, just if you click on some text, a function is called. I believe JTextPane could solve this problem using components, but I can't seem to figure it out..

Yes, this question already exists, but the other one is a duplicate, and the one it links to does NOT answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` is a satisfactory `JTextComponent`, then a `HyperlinkListener` will be invoked to perform any desired action, as shown in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447176/230513).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A JTextArea could work for this too.

- You could use a MouseListener and then translate the location of the click via `viewToModel(Point pt)`.
- You could then use `javax.swing.text.Utilities.getRowStart(textArea, offset);`  if you need the start of the row selected, and `getRowEnd(...)` for the end.
- You could have a `Map<String, SomeLink>` to see if a selected word is a linking word.

For an example of this, please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298010/522444).

Comment: Actually, I found an easier way to do it, but I have another issue...
So the solution I found was to convert the selected text into a new Component using JTextPane's insertComponent method. However, when I create a new component like this, the text associated is offset a little bit below the original line... which is quite irksome.